# Url pop up on robot framework

Tags: python, popup, robotframework

I need to verify URL pop up on robot framework 
which method robot can i use 
i use the method Location Should Be like that

```
Click element ${button}
Location Should Be  URL
Close All Browsers
```

but it doesn't work 
Any help please

Comment: It's hard to answer questions, without any code to work with.

Comment: See [ask]. Define what you expect to happen - "verify URL" is one thing, but "pop up"? Is it "url should appear", or "a pop up should be with url" - it's a guessing game. Define what "doesn't work" is - what's the output, what should have happened but doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of with variable Location Should be. Here is my sample.

My amazon.robot looks like:

```
*** Settings ***         
Resource          resource.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Open Amazon & Careers
Open Browser To Amazon
Amazon Page Should Be Open
Go To Careers Page
[Teardown]    Close Browser
```

My resource.robot looks like:

```
*** Keywords ***
Open Browser To Amazon
Open Browser    ${URL}    ${BROWSER}
Maximize Browser Window
Set Selenium Speed    ${DELAY}

Amazon Page Should Be Open
Title Should Be    Amazon.com: Online Shopping for Electronics, Apparel, Computers, Books, DVDs & more

Go To Careers Page
Wait Until Page Contains        Careers
Click Element   link=Careers
Location Should Be      https://www.amazon.jobs/
```

Selenium2Library says: *"Verifies that current URL is exactly url."*
http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html

Comment: Now it works i use this method of robot framwork :    Select Window  url=http://www.example.com/